# Why getItem is not working on ListAdapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I'm trying to create a ListAdapter for my recyclerView but the getItem(position) is not working, it asks to create the function. The code I copied and pasted the one from codelab. What can I do to fix it?

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#11

````
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WordViewHolder {
        return WordViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WordViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(current.word)
    }

    class WordViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val wordItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)

        fun bind(text: String?) {
            wordItemView.text = text
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): WordViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false)
                return WordViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    class WordsComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Word>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Word, newItem: Word): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Word, newItem: Word): Boolean {
            return oldItem.word == newItem.word
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: you sure you extending `androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter` , list adapter certainly has a protected `getItem` method

Comment: Great! It was extending androd.recyclerview.ListAdapter. Thanks

Comment: @HenriqueTavolaro if that solved it, can you mark the question as answered?

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan thanks for this comment. I had the same problem in the question. Changing from `android.widget.ListAdapter` to `androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter` solved it!

Comment: @DiegoS.Seabra you're welcome

Comment: Can you help me in java?